# Gym routine with Tennis

Tags: workout-routines, gym, stronglifts, tennis

What would be some good additional exercises to do at the gym for 2 days a week with 7 days of tennis?

Objective - Improve strength, mobility and endurance. (Not particularly in this order)

I am pretty familiar with StrongLifts 5*5, which I have been following before this, but am afraid it has to stop now (don't have enough time).

My routine, which I am aiming to follow is, 7 days tennis, Saturday Sunday gym, mainly compound movements like, squats (with lesser weight), overhead press, deadlift, bench press, pull ups, seated row/weight pull ups(that machine which has a rod).

Please help me refine this plan.

About me: 7-8 hours of sitting job, weight 60 Kgs, height 180 cm, 23 years old.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Before anyone can accurately make any recommendations, it would be helpful to know what kind of tennis specific training you're doing (ie: sprinting drills, etc). You'll probably want to end up aligning lifting days with similar tennis training days.

Comment: @AlexL The tennis routine typically includes, light warmup running, some skipping on the rope, followed by rallies and a set. For me, its fair amount of cardio, even here I am looking forward to increase my stamina. I am trying my best to incorporate a good diet.

Answer (score 3):

This link has a routine for tennis (3 or 4 days, which you can adapt to your needs):

http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/weik55.htm

And here you can find a great exercise database with video demonstration:

http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/

And this USTA link has some good warm-up, drills and strength training, although they use bands instead of dumbbells or barbells.

https://www.usta.com/Improve-Your-Game/Sport-Science/249182_Strength_Training_and_Conditioning_for_Tennis/

There is also a free app called bodyspace that you can use to track your workouts, and there are some tennis workouts in there.